# Cannot insert "subclass" object into database using EF Core code first

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-3.1

I have two classes:

```
Workout.cs:

public class Workout
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            public string Name { get; set; }
    
            public ICollection<WorkoutSet> Sets { get; set; }
    
            public DateTimeOffset FromDateTime { get; set; }
            
            public DateTimeOffset ToDateTime { get; set; }
        }
```

and I have subclass

```
WorkoutSet.cs
    
public class WorkoutSet
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            public int WorkoutId { get; set; }
            
            public Workout Workout { get; set; }
    
            public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    
            public int Type { get; set; }
    
            public int Duration { get; set; }
        }
```

This setup makes WorkoutSet have a foreign key to Workout. This is great but I have an issue inserting data into the database. I am trying to insert a new workout with new workout sets (like the definition of a workout) with following code:

```
using (IDbContextTransaction transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await _dbContext.Workouts.AddAsync(data);
                        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        await _dbContext.WorkoutSets.AddRangeAsync(data.Sets);
                        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        await transaction.CommitAsync();
                        return data;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                        throw new Exception("Cannot create workout");
                    }
                }
```

When I am debugging the application, I see that proper ID is created for a workout, I see that proper newly generated ID is created for each workoutset, but after workoutset when I call savechangesasync I receive error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert
> explicit value for identity column in table 'WorkoutSets' when
> IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

My database context looks like this:

```
public class TrainingDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TrainingDbContext(DbContextOptions<TrainingDbContext> options) : base (options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }

        public DbSet<WorkoutSet> WorkoutSets { get; set; }
    }
```

I was looking into different solutions found online like adding attributes like this to ID :

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
```

Or overriding OnModelCreating for WorkoutSet entity but no success. Every solution I found could not resolve my problem. I understand that issue is in EF Core but I am not 100% sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'WorkoutSets' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Seems you're inserting values for Id that is an identity column.

You can try not to assign value to Id property in the `Workout` and `WorkoutSet` to make it  self increasing.

Comment: I am not assigning any IDs, calling `await _dbContext.WorkoutSets.AddRangeAsync(data.Sets);` automatically assigns IDs

Comment: @zuboje there is no need to add the `subclass` object again, when you add the parent class, the subclass will be added to database at the same time.

Comment: thanks, removing those lines did solve the problem, my understanding was I had to do that separately... Thanks!